# Modifying search terms in Drupal 7 Search API

Tags: hooks, search, database

My end goal is to wrap each keyword in * essentially enabling wildcard searches (partial word search). For instance, if I type "word" into the search box I get 99 results, if I type "wor" into the search box I get 0 results, if I type "*wor*" into the search box I get 99 results. I would like to always wrap search terms in *. Below, I can successfully assign the new keys, but the search results are still not correct. When I search "wor" I still get the same results, where I would be expecting the results of "*wor*".

```
mymodule_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  $index = $query->getIndex();
  $keys = $query->getKeys();
  $wildKeys = array();
  //wrap each original keyword in *
  foreach($keys as $key => $value) {
      if(is_numeric($key)) {
          $wildKeys[$key] = "*" . $value . "*";
      }
  }
  //sets the keywords to search on to our new keywords which are wrapped in *
  $query->keys($wildKeys);
  $query->preExecute();
  $query->execute(); // Do We need this? $query->getKeys() is now correct, but search results are not as expected
  //krumo($query->getKeys());
}
```

My coworker found that his $keys were a string, vs my seeing that they were an array. I added a check for this and this code is working.

```
function mymodule_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  $index = $query->getIndex();
  $keys = $query->getKeys();
  if(is_array($query->getKeys())){
    $keys = $query->getKeys();
  }else{
    $keys = explode(" ", $query->getKeys());
  }
  $wildKeys = array();
  //wrap each original keyword in *
  foreach($keys as $key => $value) {
      if(is_numeric($key)) {
          $wildKeys[$key] = "*" . $value . "*";
      }
  }
  $wildKeys = implode(" ", $wildKeys);
  //sets the keywords to search on to our new keywords which are wrapped in *
  $query->keys($wildKeys);
  $query->preExecute();
  $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: Difficult to understand: "wor" I get none, "wor", I get results... - same with the last.

Comment: Sorry about that, edited my original question... essentially I want to use Advanced Lucene Syntax without requiring the user to enter * symbols for wildcards, I want to handle that automatically.

Comment: JUST realized what you were talking about... my asterisks were being filtered out! Fixed the original question again.

Comment: Ah yeah, now it gets clear. Last sentence it's the same.

Comment: Good question! Welcome to Drupal Answers!

Comment: If you found a working solution you should post that as an answer to your question and mark it as the right answer. That will help following visitors easily decide between the problem and the solution.